# Get size of ajax loaded images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-size

I've tried using `$element.width()` or `$element.height()` and both doesn't seem to help for retrieving values of ajax loaded images. How can I get these with either jQuery or regular JS? The images have no settings in CSS.

Comment: can you be a little more specific regarding what you mean by "ajax-loaded images"?

Comment: I assume jQuery and javascript would only work if you've specified the width and height tags on the <img> element.  If you can do this in your serverside script, do it and try again.  Otherwise, you could try to query the image with a server side script and post back the results in jquery.

Comment: I load the images using jQuery's load() function. The reason I'm not simply grabbing the width and height from the serverside output is that I don't want to set any image sizes. I tried attaching two data attributes (that contains the values) and it works but it just seems wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load content, in your ajax success use something like this

```
var real_image_sizes = {};
$('your loaded images').one('load', function() {
    //get real image size
    real_image_sizes.width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
    real_image_sizes.height = this.height; // work for in memory images.
}).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly I need to fetch the width and height before the images are placed into the DOM?

Comment: After the image is placed into the dom, after image is loaded. You load your images, place them into dom, then execute the load that will wait until image is fully loaded.

Comment: Ah! They need to be loaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just use the load handler!

```
var $img = $('<img/>').attr('src','img_url.jpg').load(function(){ 
    console.log('width: ', $img.width(), ' height: ', $img.height()); 
});
$('body').append($img);
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Dpg/)